# Want to check whether certain third-party tool is accepted by apple or not?

Tags: ios, titanium

I was just reading some stuff related to Titanium. So, i wanted to know whether Apple will accept my app or not? I think, titanium-built apps will not be facing any problems right?

Also, the MAIN thing I want to know is, suppose I am using a third-party tool. Now, I want to test whether Apple will accept it or reject my app. How can I check that?

Will I have to upload the app and then simply **WAIT** for 10-15 days to know the solution or is there something else which will let me know Apple's decision somewhat earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple will accept apps made with third-part tools, like flash, mono or Titanium.

Whether you app will be rejected is up to you, if you meet all the criteria for the app store your app will not be rejected.

Check the [App store  Submission tips](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html) to see if your matches the requirements.

Comment: but what if i want to check whether apple will accept my third-party tool or not? uploading the app on itunes is the only option???? I just wanna check it...

Comment: Yes submitting you app to Apple Review is the only way. But if your confirms to the App store guidelines why would it be rejected. What is it that makes you think your app will get rejected?

Comment: when did they start accepting mono apps again? or did they always ... and just one app developer made negative press?